# General solution to simultaneous equation of vectors

Tags: vectors

I am trying to find the general solution for $\bf{x}$ and $\bf{y}$ to the equations $ \textbf{x}+\textbf{y}=2\textbf{a},
$ and $\textbf{x.y}=c \space
$ for some real constant $c$ with $c<\bf a.a
$

The only not completely trivial progress I have made as far as I can see is getting ${\bf x.x}+{\bf y.y}=4{\bf a.a}-2c
$.

I would appreciate any help on how to proceed with this.

Comment: Suppose $a,x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$. This means that you have $2n$ unknowns and only $n+1$ equations. The problem in undetermined

Comment: As an illustration of the above, suppose one rotates $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}$ around the direction of $\mathbf{a}$. This leaves their dot product unchanged and preserves their sum, so every such rotation will give another solution.

Comment: But in terms of finding the general solution, is there a way of finding the form of all solutions, not uniquely determining $\bf x,y$ as such.